# Obtain a name of a protocol programmatically

Tags: swift, swift4

How can I retrieve the name of a protocol programmatically?

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
func printName()
}

extension SomeProtocol {
func printName() {
print("Name?")
}
}
```

Comment: `print(SomeProtocol.self)`

Comment: Oh gosh. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(SomeProtocol.self)
```

Or if you want as `String`

```
let name = String(describing: SomeProtocol.self)
print(name)
```